# Sharepoint KPI using calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, kpi

I am trying to create a KPI for the tasks schedule we have on a calendar.

The formula I have is:

```
"<div><img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-"&IF(Completed="Yes",0,2)&".gif'/></div>"
```

This works however I would like to add that if a task is (Completed="In Progress") that it changes to the yellow triangle icon.

The formula I have tried is:

```
=<div><img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-"&IF(Completed="Yes",0,2)&".gif'/><img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-"IF(Completed="In Progress",0,1)&".gif'/></div>
```

I realize that this is probably dead easy but I am new to calculated columns.

The default icon wants to be red.

Answer (score 4):

```
="<center>"&IF([Completed]="", "<img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF' border='0'/>",(IF([Completed]="In Progress","<img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF' border='0'/>", (IF([Completed]="Yes","<img src='/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF' border='0'/>")))&"</center>"
```

Remember to set the calculated column to type "Number" for the calculation to work.

[image]

Comment: Under my KPI column i now get "FAlSE" and no icons.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2010 or SharePoint 2013? Have you sett the column to "number" type?

Comment: 2007 unfortunatley.

Comment: Updated my answer so the folders points to the same directory as in your working example. Mine pointed to the SharePoint 2013 directory.. So does Dannys answer do, if you try to remove the "15" from the directory adress, he's answer should work as well.

Comment: Sorted removed the /15.. must be something to the setup of sharepoint we have. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Every version of sharepoint uses differents directorys.. so /14/ for SharePoint 2010, /15/ for SharePoint 2013.. Glad it worked out.

Comment: If you are using SharePoint 2007 I think (I am not sure) you are out of luck. The datatype=number trick to use HTML works since 2010. On 2007 you have to add an extra Javascript to a page to convert the Text to HTML; see http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/06/04/html-calculated-column-updated-script/

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct.

I suggest to rewrite it a bit, more like your original formula

If you are starting out with calculated columns it helps to keep them as short as possible and spread them over multiple lines.

```
="<img src=""/_layouts/images/kpidefault-"
  &IF([Completed]="In Progress","1", IF([Completed]="Yes","0","2"))
&".gif"">"
```

Note

- the default value is 2 , no need to use an extra IF for that
- I replaced the single quotes that open/close the src attribute with TWO double quotes, this results in a single double quote when the Formula is calculated and makes it better readable when you output the Formula as Text to verify the HTML
- the border attribute for an IMG is 0 by default, so no need to include it

More at: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How

Comment: i tried this also but i get the following under my KPI column <img src="/_layouts/15/images/kpidefault-2.gif">

Comment: You have to set the datatype of the Calculated Column to Number to make the browser execute the HTML, Single line of text will onl display the HTML as text.

Comment: Yeah it is set as number but i am using Sharepoint 2007

Comment: Sorted removed the /15.. must be something to the setup of sharepoint we have. Thanks for your help!