# Using a Calculated Column to show Images

Tags: calculated-column, kpi

Ok, I've been working on this most of yesterday and today.  I am able to render an image with the following formula -

```
    ="<div><img src='/xx/xx/PublishingImages/"&IF([Employees Submitted On Time PP1]="Yes","anchor.jpg'> ","hyphen.jpg'>")&"</div>"
```

But it either picks "yes", or no and blank.

I need to add a "NO" in there and I've tried several formulas, including this one.

```
    ="<div><img src='/xx/xxx/PublishingImages/"&IF(OR[Employees Submitted On Time PP1]="Yes","anchor.jpg', [Employees Submitted On Time PP1]="No","red-no.jpg'> ","hyphen.jpg'>")&"</div>"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
="<div><img src='/xx/xxx/PublishingImages/"
&IF(OR[Employees Submitted On Time PP1]="Yes"
    ,"anchor.jpg', [Employees Submitted On Time PP1]="No"
    ,"red-no.jpg'> ","hyphen.jpg'>")&"</div>"
```

All I did was copy your Formula and added some line breaks to see where you put all the "

That is where you are going wrong

- " quotes in the wrong places
- The OR function has missing/misplaced ()

I presume you want:

```
="<img src='/xx/xxx/PublishingImages/"
&IF(ISBLANK([Employees Submitted On Time PP1])
    ,"hyphen"
    ,IF([Employees Submitted On Time PP1]
        ,"anchor"
        ,"red-no"
        )
    )
&".jpg'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below one, if you have used Yes/No column

```
="<DIV><img src='"&IF([Completed?], "/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-
0.GIF", "/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF")&"'></DIV>"
```

Ref : http://www.dreamsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-simple-kpi-using-calculated-columns/

Comment: similar issue http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131487/sharepoint-kpi-using-calculated-columns